# Hey I'm implementing a gridview in a fragment...but im totally clueless about these errors

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

Hey I want to implement this grid view given in link
[Link][1]http://sujewan.blogspot.in/2013/08/9-android-custom-gridview.html

but i want to do this in a fragment....but here i am stuck with these two errors....

Here's my fragment class....

I've tagged the lines in which i'm experiencing errors

```
public class FragmentGrid extends Fragment{

GridView gridview;
GridViewAdapter gridviewAdapter;
ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();



  @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize the GUI Components
    gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView);





    fillData(); // Insert The Data
      // Set the Data Adapter
    gridviewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_grid, data);
    gridview.setAdapter(gridviewAdapter);


    /* ----- ERRRORR ------*/
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
             String message = "Clicked : " + data.get(position).getTitle();
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}




// Insert The Data
private void fillData()
{
    data.add(new Item("Facebook", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.athletics)));
    data.add(new Item("Twitter", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bowls)));
    data.add(new Item("Linked In", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boxing)));
    data.add(new Item("Google", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cycling)));
    data.add(new Item("Yahoo", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.netball)));
    data.add(new Item("YouTube", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.swimming)));
    data.add(new Item("Flickr", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hockey)));
    data.add(new Item("Whatsapp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.judo)));
    data.add(new Item("Blogger", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.triathlon)));
}

}
```

After Taking all the help from AlexBalo....i was able to fix my issues..
Finally my class looks like this...

```
public class FragmentGrid extends Fragment{

GridView gridview;
GridViewAdapter gridviewAdapter;
ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     RelativeLayout fragmentLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view, container, false);

return fragmentLayout;
}


  @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize the GUI Components
    gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView);



  //  gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this); /* ----- ERRRORR ------*/


    fillData(); // Insert The Data
      // Set the Data Adapter
    gridviewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_grid, data);
   gridview.setAdapter(gridviewAdapter);


    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
             String message = "Clicked : " + data.get(position).getTitle();
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}




// Insert The Data
private void fillData()
{
    data.add(new Item("Facebook", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.athletics)));
    data.add(new Item("Twitter", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bowls)));
    data.add(new Item("Linked In", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boxing)));
    data.add(new Item("Google", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cycling)));
    data.add(new Item("Yahoo", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.netball)));
    data.add(new Item("YouTube", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.swimming)));
    data.add(new Item("Flickr", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hockey)));
    data.add(new Item("Whatsapp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.judo)));
    data.add(new Item("Blogger", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.triathlon)));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fragment class is not implementing onItemClickListener. Try this

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        }
    });
```

**Edit:**

And use this method instead (I suggest creatin a specific layout for the fragment):

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        LinearLayout fragmentLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout_resource, container, false);

        gridView = (GridView) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.yourGridView);
        and here all the rest of the code...

        return fragmenLayout;
    }
```

Comment: So i did wat u said.....put my code from onItemCLick into this...and here's the error i get now-----
The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})

Comment: Can you update the class you posted with your new code please?

Comment: And also move the setOnItemClickListener after setAdapter method

Comment: import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; 

Check if you have this between your imports and in case remove that one

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Comment: umm...neva had tht import..so added it....but now i have error on getApplicationContext() in Toast.makeTest method......

The error simple says ---
The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}

Comment: use getActivity instead

Comment: A'right no more errors...lemme run it...hope i won't be getting any nullpointers with getActivtiy

Comment: Well in this case getActivity is called when you click on an item so it should be there because you are looking at it :D

Comment: got the nullpointer error....saying NullPointerException at OnActivityCreated...according to the logcat....Im not even getting the view...forget the on click

Comment: move everything you have in onActivityCreated into onCreateView. You should think about having a layout for your fragment instead of getting the grid from the activity. Check my edited answer above

Comment: alright this is what i did...i just simple returned the view from onCreateView...and then put everything in OnActivtiyCreated method...and it works so sexy now...THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP